# Accidentally installed mysql twice

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, installation, rubygems

First with the typical .DMG installation, and the second with the Brew.

I was getting a .sock error with the Brew installation, so I uninstalled it with `brew uninstall mysql`

And now when I try to use the original mysql I get this

```
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
```

Yikes. I completely removed mysql and anything related to it as so :

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Then I redownloaded it, ( tried this twice with both 5.5 and 5.1 ), and installed it, used arch flags for my 64 bit mac os x macbook pro.

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/mysql_config
```

And I got the same error:

```
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
```

Anyone know what could possibly going wrong here? Is there something remote that I didn't delete yet?

Comment: This question is not for this site. Try http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

This error effects so many Rails users, that's why its here on StackOverflow.com.

Here's the issue. MySQL 5.5.9 **does not work with the latest mysql gem 2.8.1**

You must install the MySQL Library 5.5.1 as of 2/24/2011.

And following the uninstall directions above. I used this as my archflags installation :

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.1.55-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
```